# Sqldependency:Query Notifications not receiving properly

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008-r2, service-broker, sqldependency

We are using SQldependency for Query Notifications in our program. In our webserver we have database from which we send query notification. The application runs in our office PC. It works fine and I do receive instant notification on any changes in table. But for last few days sometimes I get error. The application is does not get any notification even though changes are there. The problem comes at random time. I also confirmed the internet connection by using continuous ping to the server and it was proper. Reopening my application solved the problem temporarily. But I want to know what may be reason for this problem. How can I troubleshoot it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think anyone can guess what is wrong with your deployment, w/o any info. My advice is to read [The Mysterious Notification](http://rusanu.com/2006/06/17/the-mysterious-notification/), [Troubleshooting Query Notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177469.aspx) and [Troubleshooting Dialogs](http://rusanu.com/2005/12/20/troubleshooting-dialogs/). With a better understand of how it works and what to look for, perhaps you can diagnose the issue.